# href for a link with special characters does not work in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, xelatex

I want to compile the following:

`href{https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/3.1-estimation-of-the-population-mean.html#:~:text=%23%20set%20seed%20for,%23%3E%20%5B1%5D%208.257893}{this link.}`

```
> \frametitle {Link to Highlighted Text} You can access the URL with th\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex
            
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

But it is completely unrelated to frametitle. The problem is with # sign and other special characters.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to decode the url then escape the # characters, i.e. replacing it with \#.

BTW, the decoded URL I got is `https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/3.1-estimation-of-the-population-mean.html#:~:text=# set seed for,#> [1] 8.257893`